# SFMC Stop and Publish via API leaves Journey in invalid Draft status

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I made a script to stop and start published journeys for the purpose of refreshing assets.

After the script runs, some journeys are left in the "Draft" status. Those "Draft" journeys cannot be activated because they produce an undefined validation error - Errors array is empty in the API call. Journeys were published before so there are no new validation errors. If I delete the draft and make a new version, there are no validation errors.

How is that possible and why does it happen? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem. You need to publish the journey with the api in order to change the status from draft back to published/unpublished.